# Store in a variable a path read in a file (script shell)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file with several path inside with the shape:

`directory1/directory2/directory3`

I would like to put one of these path inside a variable in a script shell, to use it as a path.

**I tried :**

```
name="`sed -n 2p file`"
```

**But i cannot use a command like :** `cd "../$name"`. I have an error message saying this folder doesn't exist.

Do you have an idea how i can perform this on my script?

Comment: What should `name` contain for above input (`directory1/directory2/directory3`)? I guess, `file=directory1/directory2/directory3/somefile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use cut,

```
name=`cut -f1 -d "/" file`  # instead of f1 use f2 for directory2 and so on
```

like this,

```
[root@giam46 ~]# cat sample.txt
Desktop/MEF_R400
[root@giam46 ~]# name=`cut -f1 -d "/" sample.txt`
[root@giam46 ~]# echo $name
Desktop
[root@giam46 ~]# cd /root/${name}
[root@giam46 Desktop]# pwd
/root/Desktop
[root@giam46 Desktop]# cd ..
[root@giam46 ~]# pwd
/root
[root@giam46 ~]#
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, it will be enough

```
name=`sed -n 2p file`
```

Comment: This not solve my problem, there is the same error message :)